# Big file upload failure using django-ajax-uploader

Tags: ajax, django, uploader, ajaxuploader

I'm trying to use `django-ajax-uploader` in my website, which works just fine in LAN, but while I upload my file through internet, it only uploads a file of no more than 2MB, any file bigger than 2MB will fail.
I changed the default **BUFFER_SIZE** to 64MB but still did not work. And I have tested Chrome , Safari and Firefox, all failed.

Have any of you ever met this problem before?
Thx :)

ps:
I've seen [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501213/cant-upload-5mb-file-using-ajax-file-uploader) , but I'm quite sure it's a different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What frontend server do you use (Apache, nginx)? You need to check it settings.

**EDIT**: If you're using nginx you need something like this:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name example.com;

        client_max_body_size    64m;
}
```

For apache something like so:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

You could check that the problem is with the frontend server by:

1. run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` on production server - this runs 'developer' server on port 8000 and allows to connect from your computer
2. go to `yourdoamin.com:8000` and try to upload a large file. It should work fine.

Comment: Its Nginx, but is it a buffer_size problem? I mean, while in LAN, uploading a much larger file is ok.

Comment: Default value of `client_max_body_size` for nginx is 1mb. Ngxinx drops all requests with body larger than this value. You could see this in log files. Look at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size for more details.